# Linux kernel conntrack drop statistics

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, iptables, netfilter, conntrack

In Linux kernel conntrack subsystem sources I see a lot of statistic ticks like [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.19.144/source/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_core.c#L1608):

```
ret = resolve_normal_ct(net, tmpl, skb, dataoff, pf, protonum, l4proto);
if (ret < 0) {
    /* Too stressed to deal. */
    NF_CT_STAT_INC_ATOMIC(net, drop);
    ret = NF_DROP;
    goto out;
}
```

But I really can't figure out how in Linux (from user-mode) can I check this statistics. F.e. where can I find conntrack drops count? There is nothing similar in `/proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack*`.
Sorry if obvious.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can see the statics in some tools like `netstat` or `ss` or `nstat`.

Then the problem about how the `NF_CT_STAT_INC_ATOMIC` counts drop need to trace the function itself. I think it's more interesting to do it by yourself since you are curious about it.

`#define NF_CT_STAT_INC_ATOMIC(net, count) this_cpu_inc((net)->ct.stat->count)`

From here we can see that actually count is in ct.stat->drop. By searching this you can find your answer.